# Python Logging: Multiple Loggers and Decorator

Tags: python, logging

How can I get logging from within a logger in one module and still use a log decorator?

I have this basic log decorator in logger.py:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("dec_log.log")
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
 
        func_info = f"\n{func.__name__}, {func.__module__}"
        logger.info(func_info)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)

        return res

    return wrapper
```

This works fine, but then sometimes I want to log something within the function of another module.

So, for example, if I have main.py set up like this:

```
logg = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logg.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_format = logging.Formatter(
    "%(levelname)s:%(lineno)d:%(message)s",
)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("main_log.log")
file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
logg.addHandler(file_handler)

@log
def divide_func(a, b):
    try:
        res = a / b
    except DivisionByZeroError:
        logg.critical(f"Can't divide by zero: {a} / {b}")
    else:
        return res
```

This doesn't work. I get dec_log.log file with that info, but I don't get a main_log.log file with the logger info. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How and when do you import `log`?  If you're doing `import *` and you do it *after* defining the local `logger` the import is shadowing it.

Comment: `from logger import log` at top of file

Comment: Stick a `print(logger)` in your `except DivisionByZeroError` and in your `log`.  Do they both have the same `logger` object?  Is your code even reaching your `except`?

Comment: I just changed `logger` to `logg` in main.py and the problem remains.

Comment: When you call `logg.critical` in `main.py` does it log to `dec_log.log` or does it just not log anything at all?

Comment: Does nothing. Doesn't log to dec_log.log

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a way to make it sort of work, but not sure if this would be considered a proper method:

In `main.py`:

```
From logger import logger, log

@log
def divide_func(a, b):
    try:
        res = a / b
    except DivisionByZeroError:
        logger.critical(f"Can't divide by zero: {a} / {b}")
    else:
        return res
```

This doesn't do exactly what I want, but close enough for now that I can stop messing with setting up a logger.